# What's the best approch for animated links?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

So there is this page I'm working on that has sentences that will function as links that are laid out as inline-block. What I ultimately want is for the links on the page to be animated to simulate twinkling stars that stop the animation on the hover.

Again, this seems like a "in over my head" situation because nothing I've tried quite works out. One important thing a lot of solutions miss is I'd like to have a random speed and delay for each sentence (star) animation so it's not just one pulsing block of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... Do you have a specific method you were considering/have tried? It seems to me that the easiest way to do what you want would be to create a few gifs which sparkle how you want them to, then set the sparkles as a background... You could then easily use the :hover property in your CSS style sheet to change the background of the element.

Would something like that work?

Also... Not to dis your idea or anything, but as a user, that would drive me up the wall... It's a 'cool' effect at first, but quickly devolves into a nuisance. (I say this from personal experience gained from a similar animation/effect.)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I also think you're right on the UX front.